# trouble filtering items for tag groups in mongodb using $and and $in operators

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

this is the find() that i'm trying to run

```
 Item.find({'tags.id':{ $and:
  [
    {
      $in: [ 
        '530f728706fa296e0a00000a', 
        '5351d9df3412a38110000013' 
      ]
    },
    {
      $in: [ 
        '530f728706fayy6e0a00000a', 
        '5351d9df3412zz8110000013' 
      ]
    }
  ]
}}, function(err, items){
     //callback
     console.log(err)
})
```

and this is the error:

> [Error: Can't use $and with ObjectId.]

---

I found out that the way I was building the previous query was invalid, but now the problem is that when I try to build a query in JS it gets apostrophes added to it:

a js built query attempt:

var tags =
    { $and:
      [
        {
          'tags.id': {
            $in: [ 
              '530f728706fa296e0a00000a'
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          'tags.id': {
            $in: [ 
              '5351d9df3412a38110000013' 
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  console.log("tags")
the log :

{ '$and': [ { 'tags.id': [Object] }, { 'tags.id': [Object] } ] }

the extra apostrophes break the mongo db $and and $in functionality, is there a way to prevent adding them ?

Answer (score 2):

The usage is incorrect, **`$and`** is an overall modifier and not an argument that can be assigned to a specific field. If anything you should have this:

```
 Item.find({ "$and":
  [
    { "tags._id": {
      $in: [ 
        '530f728706fa296e0a00000a', 
        '5351d9df3412a38110000013' 
      ] }
    },
    {
      "tags.id": { $in: [ 
        '530f728706fayy6e0a00000a', 
        '5351d9df3412zz8110000013' 
      ]}
    }
  ]
```

But that also does not make any sense. All queries in MongoDB are implicitly a logical "and" for all conditions.

What you really seem to want to do is match the documents having either combination of  **both** of those values within your "tags" array. There are two approaches to the depending on your version of MongoDB.

For versions under 2.6:

```
Item.find({
    "$or": [
        { "$and": [
              { "tags.id": "530f728706fa296e0a00000a" },
              { "tags.id": "5351d9df3412a38110000013" }

        ]},
        { "$and": [
              { "tags.id": "530f728706fayy6e0a00000a" },
              { "tags.id": "5351d9df3412zz8110000013" }
        ]} 
    ]
},
```

And in version 2.6 and above this is slightly nicer using the [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator:

```
Item.find({
    "$or": [
        { "tags.id": { 
            "$all": [
                "530f728706fa296e0a00000a",
                "5351d9df3412a38110000013"
            ]
        }},
        { "tags.id": { 
            "$all": [
                "530f728706fayy6e0a00000a",
                "5351d9df3412zz8110000013"
            ]
        }}
    ]
},
```

Note that [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) is present in earlier versions but works differently, so the former use case applies when you want this type of result.

The **`$in`** operator will only test if **either** value given was present, which given the combinations you are using does not seem to be what you want.